# What is the name of that spider correlation graphic?

Tags: data-visualization

What is the name of a graphic like that? I need to know it to search for the correct functions in `R` or other statistic software.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't want to give a name to a graph without obvious merit....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the graph devised by Florence Nightingale to display mortality in the British army. It has become called a coxcomb chart although she probably did not call it that. It is similar to a rose chart. It could also be a polar area chart. I am not aware of how you get them in R and anyway software advice is for another site.

Comment: (+1) Also radial chart.